# Table cell hyperlink without text underline

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a table in powerpoint 2007.

I have one slide corresponding to each cell of the table in same presentation and I want to create hyperlinks on each cell.

But, I don't want the cell text to go blue and underlined after I create the hyperlink.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Perhaps, create hyperlink for table cell instead of text or change some setting so that hyperlinks are not colored and underlined.

I want this presentation to be redistributable though. So, if solution involves changing some setting in Powerpoint then it should persist across multiple systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerPoint 2007 you can link shapes, not just text. Instead of hyperlinking text fields directly, link the *box* containing the text instead.

Insert a box in your cell by going to Insert > Shapes and draw an empty box. Right-click the box and choose format shape:

- Choose 'solid fill' and make the background color of box same as the cell color
- Choose 'no line' (make the box borderless), and click 'close'

Next, right-click the box again and choose 'Edit Text'. Type in the text you want to hyperlink to another slide. Change the text color to any color you want from the Home tab.

Now, instead of choosing the *text* and creating a hyperlink, choose the box instead and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. This will allow you to link the box to the slide.

When you convert to a PDF, the hyperlink works nicely through the box, without any underlining. Note that if you want to navigate to the hyperlink within PowerPoint, the box has to be selected and not the text.

Comment: yeah. i had considered that. but my table has 90 odd cells with various shapes of different sizes. so, this option will me draw 90 boxes which i am not quite ready to do.

Comment: i found an improvement over this. it still needs drawing boxes. but instead of matching fill colours, we can set any fill colour with 100% transparency.....but, that still makes me draw all those boxes..

Comment: @tumchaaditya I guess if you were populating these tables ***from scratch*** it takes almost the same effort to create these linked boxes. In your case, to convert all cells would take some additional effort. Aside from this, I don't see a way to tell PowerPoint to identify the *content of each cell* and link it to other slides. I'll be very interested if some finds a way though